# RAID 1 + 0, Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, raid

I create the meta devices:

> ```
> metainit d102 1 1 /dev/dsk/c1t2d0s6
> metainit d103 1 1 /dev/dsk/c1t3d0s6
> metainit d104 1 1 /dev/dsk/c1t4d0s6
> metainit d105 1 1 /dev/dsk/c1t5d0s6
> ```

then I make the mirrors :

> ```
> metainit d120 -m d102
> metattach d120 d104
>
> metainit d121 -m d103
> metattach d121 d105
> ```

and least, I want to make the stripe with :

> metainit d130 1 2 d120 d121

and the system answers : d120 is a metadevice. metainit seems to want only a physical component !

So how can I create RAID 1 + 0

Comment: it's not SDS, but you can do that with ZFS.  `zpool create tank mirror c1t2d0 c1t3d0 mirror c1t4d0 c1t5d0`.  do you absolutely have to use older-style SDS metadevices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SDS, you can only stripe physical disks.  If you create a mirror of two equal stripes (a RAID 0+1 volume), SDS will "optimize" that by turning it into a RAID 1+0 volume.  So do:

```
metainit d120 1 2 /dev/dsk/c1t2d0s6 /dev/dsk/c1t4d0s6
metainit d121 1 2 /dev/dsk/c1t3d0s6 /dev/dsk/c1t5d0s6
metainit d130 -m d120
metattach d130 d121
```

Reference: [The Stripe/Mirror Redundancy Experiment with Disksuite](http://chrismiles.info/unix/sun/dsraid10.txt)

Comment: This is the RAID 0+1 implementation.
so, there is no implementation for RAID 1+0 on Solaris ?

Comment: If you read the reference link, you'll see that, correct, there is no specific implementation of RAID 1+0 using SDS. SDS will optimize a properly configured RAID 0+1 by implementing it as a RAID 1+0 array. You have to trust that it behaves this way, and the reference link offers up proof that it does.